# Unresolved reference message in list using python

Tags: python, list, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make use of a list I created outside of the function it was created in. I have an original list of objects (my_list) which has been created before the function. I use the function to create a new list of selected objects using input and this new list is the list i want to use in the rest of the code. But when I try to print the list outside of the function its not recognised - Could anybody help please.

## code below.

```
def get_input_entity(prompt):

    new_object_list = []

    while True:
        chosen_object = input(prompt)
        if chosen_object in my_list:
            new_object_list.append(chosen_entity)
            # allows user to break out of loop on carriage return
        if chosen_object == '\r':
            break
            # allows user to let new list = copy of old list then exit input
        if chosen_object == 'all':
            new_object_list = my_list.copy()
            break
        return chosen_object


print(get_input_entity('Enter entities separated by space'))
# unresolved reference new object list message
print(new_object_list)
```

Comment: Objects created inside a function are only available within that function. They cease to exist once the function returns. You need to declare it `global` to use it afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the global keyword.

You can't modify a global variable from inside a function without using the global keyword.

See: [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

```
new_object_list = []
my_list = []


def get_input_object(prompt):
    global my_list, new_object_list

    while True:
        chosen_object = input(prompt)
        if chosen_object in my_list:
            new_object_list.append(chosen_object)
        if chosen_object == '\r':
            break
        if chosen_object == 'all':
            new_object_list = my_list.copy()
            break
    return chosen_object


print(get_input_object('Enter entities separated by space'))
print(new_object_list)
```

However this isn't a great idea and is kind of confusing...why not simply pass your list as a parameter and return a new list with the `chosen_object` - negating any need for globals i.e.

```
def get_input_object(prompt, original_list):
    output = []
    while True:
        chosen_object = input(prompt)
        if chosen_object in original_list:
            output.append(chosen_object)
        if chosen_object == '\r':
            break
        if chosen_object == 'all':
            output = original_list.copy()
            break
    return chosen_object, output


chosen, new_list = get_input_object('Enter entities separated by space')

print(chosen)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: this produces `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. let me help you. first make it `global` and then assign it `[ ]`

Comment: @InfinityTM - I'm not sure what you mean...it is there is/wasn't a syntax error simply an unresolved reference...

Comment: It your unedited answer, it was `global new_object_list = [] `. that produced the error

Comment: Hi Fraser - your answer worked if I took out the original_list from the def statement ( so used the second answer you suggested without the globals). Is that just because the original_list which has been populated earlier in the code already exists? There is obviously a reason why you included there so just checking

Comment: @Sid - yes, I just added it for completeness...really globals aren't a great thing - they can be tricky and hide what a function is actually doing. It is usually best with functions to simply supply what they need as parameters and return their result or results.